# Can not update first character of a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

I have the following code that is supposed to capitalise the first letter of each word. However the first character, arr[i][0] is not getting updated. I ended up doing arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1) which worked but I do not understand why the below does not work.

```
function titleCase(string) {
  const arr = string.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i][0] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase();
  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: strings are immutable, but you could split the string and join it, ow use slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because strings are immutable in JavaScript, which means you cannot change them. Every time you try to modify a string, you are effectively creating a new string with the changes.

So when you do `arr[i][0]`, it's not a reference to the first character, it is a reference to a copy of the first character. And since you're not keeping that reference (i.e. by assigning it to a variable), it is lost.

The way you fixed it `arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1)` is one good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As other point out, strings are *immutable* in JavaScript, meaning you cannot alter their values. If you want to make the first letter of a string upper case, you would have to construct a *new* string

```
str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
```

Or more generically, if we had uppercase at a specific index, `i`

```
str.slice(0,i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1)
```

We can make a function `toUpperCaseAt` which takes a string and an index and performs this operation for us.

```
const toUpperCaseAt = (str = "", i = 0) =>
  i >= str.length
    ? str
    : str.slice (0, i) + str [i] .toUpperCase () + str.slice (i + 1)
```

Next, we write a simple recursive function `titleCase` that steps through the string, one letter at a time.

- base case: the index is out of bounds – return the input string
- inductive case 1: the index is not out of bounds and the index is 0 – the first letter should always be capitalized
- inductive case 2: the index is not out bounds, not 0, and the index currently references a space char – uppercase the *next* letter
- inductive case 3: the index is not out of bounds, not 0, and not a space – advance to the next index

This answer does not need to rely upon high-level built-in functions like `String.prototype.split` or `Array.prototype.join` – instead it shows you how to achieve the result using simple functions of your own creation.

```js
const titleCase = (str = "", i = 0) =>
  i >= str.length
    ? str
    : i === 0
      ? titleCase (toUpperCaseAt (str, i), 1)
      : str [i] === " "
        ? titleCase (toUpperCaseAt (str, i + 1), i + 1)
        : titleCase (str, i + 1)

console.log (titleCase ('hello, my name is me.'))
// Hello, My Name Is Me.
```

We can even remove the `String.prototype.slice` dependency if we're unsure of how that works

```
const slice = (str = "", from = 0, to = str.length) =>
  from >= to
    ? ''
    : str [from] + slice (str, from + 1, to)
```

The whole thing together now

```js
const slice = (str = "", from = 0, to = str.length) =>
  from >= to
    ? ""
    : str [from] + slice (str, from + 1, to)

const toUpperCaseAt = (str = "", i = 0) =>
  i >= str.length
    ? str
    : slice (str, 0, i) + str [i] .toUpperCase () + slice (str, i + 1)

const titleCase = (str = "", i = 0) =>
  i >= str.length
    ? str
    : i === 0
      ? titleCase (toUpperCaseAt (str, i), 1)
      : str [i] === " "
        ? titleCase (toUpperCaseAt (str, i + 1), i + 1)
        : titleCase (str, i + 1)
        
console.log (titleCase ('hello, my name is me.'))
// Hello, My Name Is Me.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function titleCase(string) {
  const arr = string.split(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  
    // arr[i] is a String!!!
    const word = arr[i];
    
    // now, in order to target and mutate the [0]th key we need an Array:
    let charsArray = word.split("");
    
    // Now you can do .toUpperCase() on the [0]th array key
    charsArray[0] = charsArray[0].toUpperCase();
    
    // Convert Array to string and update arr[i]
    arr[i] = charsArray.join("");

  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}

console.log( titleCase("hello world") )
```

or you could [simply use `String.prototype.replace()`<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const titleCase = str => str.replace(/\b(\w)/g, f => f.toUpperCase());

console.log( titleCase("hello world") )
```